# Is Kafka Stream really Real Time?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Stream API to test some functionality. 
I have a Stream like :

```
KStream<String, UnifiedData> stream = builder.stream("topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Data.class)));

stream.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getMetadata().getId())
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1000)))
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .map((key, value) -> {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    return KeyValue.pair(key.toString(), value);
                });
```

I found 2 stranges behaviours will producing some data in my topic :

- First : I don't get an output for each data produced. For example, If I produce 20 messages with no delay, I will just get a `20` as output and not something like `1 2 3....`
- Second : There is like 20 seconds of delay between the time I produce my message and the time the `System.out.println(value)` print the result in my console

So, do you think that this behaviour is totally normal ? Or May I have a configuration problem with my kafka ?

I'm using Kafka 1.0.1, Kafka Stream 1.0.1, Java 8 and Spring-Boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Kafka Streams uses a cache to "dedupliate" consecutive outputs from an aggregation to reduce the downstream load.

You can disable caching globally by setting `cache.max.bytes.buffering=0` in your `KafkaStreams` config. As an alternative, it's also possible to disable cache per store individually, by passing in a `Materialized` parameter into the aggregation operator.

Furthermore, all caches are flushed on commit and the default commit interval is 30 seconds. Thus, it makes sense that you see output after 30 seconds. If you disable caching, commit interval will not have any impact on the behavior any longer.

For more details see: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html